# Changing scale and rounding off Target

Tags: regression, machine-learning, data-transformation, data-preprocessing, scales

I am training a regression machine learning model to predict an airplane's maximum take-off weight based on some pre-project features. The airplane weights in the dataset I'm working with are registered in kilograms. The model is not expected to be highly precise; it is intended to provide a robust estimation of the weight, with an accuracy of approximately 0.1 tons. Given these requirements, would the model benefit from a target transformation that changes its scale and rounds off the target value (e.g., changing 102,341 kg to 102.3 tons)? Or should I perform this transformation after my model predicts the weight? What should this process to be called?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever make your data less precise? By doing this you would be intentionally handicapping your model by preventing it from being less precise. I highly doubt that “accuracy of approximately 0.1 tons” means “not better than”. Quality of your training data forces the upper bound for accuracy. The model can be arbitrarily worse than this because the end result would depend on the quality of the data plus the approximation error of the model itself.